# No input file specified PHP fastcgi

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just upgraded my PHP version to PHP 5.6.x running Fastcgi. I got a problem with a web application after te upgrade. When I remove the one RewriteRule the web application gives me the error: - No input file specified.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m/
RewriteCond $1 ^(index.php|media/images|media/js|media/css)
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(media/.*.(gif|jpe?g|png))$ application/views/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: make sure extension is enable : mod_rewrite

Comment: I checked https://datevoorjongeren.nl/m/check.php

Comment: it seems mod_rewrite is not enable.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gDm8iqY.png Modules are loaded

Comment: you can come on chat for this prob. DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

Comment: I think I found the issue I switched the PHP from Fastcgi to php-FPM and the htaccess is now working

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and found it was due to a setting in my .user.ini file. I should note that the setting in this file was overwriting the value in php.ini, so you may want to check the settings there for this issue.

Anyway, I had pulled the php site from a Plesk instance and was trying to run under IIS. Apparently there is a setting, "[open_basedir](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404214/how-do-i-set-the-path-for-open_basedir)", that tells the php engine what directory-tree the site can access.  In my case, the setting was set in the .user.ini file, and it was hardcoded to a path that was relevant only to the plesk server it was originally hosted on.

I'm not a php developer, so forgive me any terms I may have used incorrectly.